# Installing a particular assembly first

Tags: castle-windsor

I have multiple assemblies in my application, some of which contain installers.  However, I need to ensure that the installers in my entry assembly are run first.  (My application defines some decorators, and install order matters.)

I tried this:

```
_container.Install(FromAssembly.Containing<MyApplication>());
_container.Install(FromAssembly.InDirectory(new AssemblyFilter(applicationDirectory)));
```

but that runs the installers in my application assembly twice, causing a registration exception.

I can mitigate this by creating a field in the installers to track whether that installer has run, and return if it has, but that seems hacky.

Is there a proper way to have Windsor install a single assembly, then the rest of the assemblies in a directory without duplication?

I think what I'd like to do is something like this

```
_container.Install(FromAssembly.InDirectory(new AssemblyFilter(applicationDirectory))
                               .SkipAlreadyRegistered());
```

or

```
_container.Install(FromAssembly.InDirectory(new AssemblyFilter(applicationDirectory))
                               .Except(FromAssembly.Containing<MyApplication>()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using InstallerFactory to alter the order?

```
public class AppFirstFactory: InstallerFactory
{
    public override IEnumerable<Type> Select(IEnumerable<Type> installerTypes)
    {
        return installerTypes.OrderBy(x => x.Assembly == GetType().Assembly ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

Then to register:

```
_container.Install(FromAssembly.InDirectory(new AssemblyFilter(applicationDirectory), new AppFirstFactory()));
```

Comment: I like this.  I'll try it tomorrow!

Comment: Very nice solution.  Works perfectly!